# Ember Rails authentication via simple-auth and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I have tried everithing starting following this guide

> https://adibsaad.com/blog/setting-up-ember-cli-with-a-rails-back-end-and-token-authentication-authorization

but still it does not work. When I try to reach pages that are protected with authentication token the server give me "unauthorized 401". Here

> https://github.com/francescabarbazeni87/Ember-Devise-Simple-Auth-Example-

there is my code for the server and client side. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please paste your HTTP request from console

Comment: Please consider adding [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, instead of linking to external site. See ["How do I ask good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):help others reproduce the problem section.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

  # Enter the normal Devise authentication path,
  # using the token authenticated user if available
  #before_filter :authenticate_user! <-----you dont need this line...delete or comment it out
```